# ZKoss Framework Error 404 in Hello World example

Tags: java, zk

I followed the steps in ZKoss Framwork in creating Hello World example.
Basically, when you try to create a new ZK Project, supposedly you don't need to change anything to be able to run Hello World screen.

> > [Hello World Tutorial](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Installation_Guide/Quick_Start/Create_and_Run_Your_First_ZK_Application_with_Eclipse_and_ZK_Studio)

However, I keep on receiving the following error :
HTTP Status 404 - /ZKTest/

[image: Here's the screenshot of my newly created ZK Project :]

Could you please assist me on this?

Here's [index.zul] :

```
<?page title="Auto Generated index.zul"?>
<window title="Hello World!!" border="normal" width="200px">

<label value="You are using: ${desktop.webApp.version}"/>

</window>
```

Here's [web.xml] :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>ZKTest</display-name>
    <listener>
        <description>
        Used to cleanup when a session is destroyed</description>
        <display-name>ZK Session cleaner</display-name>
        <listener-class>org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.HttpSessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <description>
        The ZK loader for ZUML pages</description>
        <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>update-uri</param-name>
            <param-value>/zkau</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <description>
        The asynchronous update engine for ZK</description>
        <servlet-name>auEngine</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.zul</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.zhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>auEngine</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/zkau/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.zul</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Post code and error message please

Comment: i have already posted index.zul and web.xml. what code/file am I lacking here for you to be able to help me with this problem?

Comment: can you please post the stack trace ?

Comment: I could not seem to find any problem in the stack trace. However, what I did is that I removed another running application from my Tomcat Server, restarted the server and then re-run the application. It solved my problem. Thank you so much pathfinder2104 for your time. I really appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Are you sure that `/ZKTest/` is correct? Try opening `/` (e.g. `localhost:8080/`) and see if it gives you an index listing you webapp.